# Cómo mantener un $_SESSION mediante window.location.replace

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando mantener una sesión de usuario iniciada hasta mi siguiente página, pero no me está recogiendo en mi segunda página el $_SESSION. Normalmente utilizo header para redireccionar a otra página, pero en este caso no me estaba funcionando, así que he utilizado la función window.location.replace. No sé si es problema de que tengo algo más o es que no puedo enviar sesiones de esta manera, he estado probando varias maneras de enviar el $_SESSION y tampoco me funcionan. Os muestro mi código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      .container{margin-top:100px}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php

  session_start();
   
  // Obtengo los datos cargados en el formulario de login.
  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
   
  // Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
  $nombreServidor = "localhost";
  $nombreUsuario = "x";
  $passwordBaseDeDatos = "x";
  $nombreBaseDeDatos = "x";
  // Crear conexión con la base de datos.
  $conn = new mysqli($nombreServidor, $nombreUsuario, $passwordBaseDeDatos, $nombreBaseDeDatos);
   
  // Validar la conexión de base de datos.
  if ($conn ->connect_error) {
    die("Error de conexión: " . $conn ->connect_error);
  }
   
  // Consulta segura para evitar inyecciones SQL. 
  $sql = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombreUsuario='$usuario' AND claveUsuario='$password'");

  $resultado = $conn->query($sql);


  if($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario; //si el usuario se encuentra, crea la sesión de usuario
    echo "<script> window.location.replace('picar.php'); </script>";
    } else {
        echo "<br> <div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
        El usuario o contraseña no es correcto. <a href='login.php'>Inténtelo de nuevo.</a>
        </div>";
    }
 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Luego, como prueba, en otra página estoy intentando simplemente mostrar el nombre del usuario que ha iniciado sesión y no aparece, esto es una prueba de la otra página para ver si era la forma que tenía de mostrar el $
_SESSION el problema, pero esto sí me funciona sin variables.

```
<?php
// start a session
session_start();
 
// initialize session variables
$_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'] = '1';
$_SESSION['logged_in_user_name'] = 'prueba';
 
// access session variables
echo $_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'];
echo $_SESSION['logged_in_user_name'];
?>
```

¡Muchas gracias de antemano si podéis echarme una mano con esto!

Comment: El archivo cuando ingresas los datos te manda a picar.php ??

Comment: Ademas estas creando la session usuario $_SESSION['usuario'] y en otra pagina quieres mostrar $_SESSION['logged_in_user_id'] cuando deberias mostrar la session usuario

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @ernestojimenez, `session_start();` debe ir antes de cualquier salida (espacios, saltos de línea, HTML, etc.), porque requiere enviar encabezados al navegador para poder establecer la _cookie_ de sesión.